# Artisan serve doesn't work and it deletes server.php

Tags: php, laravel, server

I have just install xampp and laravel
and when I create a new Laravel project, and run php artisan serve, after a few seconds the server quits, and if I rerun it and go to 127.0.0.1, it gives me the error:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\new_project\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

**And it's deleted the server.php file in the new project.**

- Windows 10
- Laravel 5.8.34
- PHP 7.3.8
- Composer 1.9.0

  ps : i haven't any antivirus installed

Comment: I don't understand; if you have xampp installed, then why not just run laravel app as a virtual host via apache2, instead of running artisan serve?

Comment: ooh! is there any way to make the virtual host for a Laravel Project in Xampp!

Answer (score 0):

php artisan:serve will host the application on 127.0.0.1:8000

You can create a virtual host in **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**.

```
<VirtualHost myproject.test:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\public"
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And also edit your hosts file 
**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**

Add the following line: **127.0.0.1  myproject.test**